# Issue with Perl hash uniqueness

Tags: perl, hash

I am very inexperience with perl, and I have a simple task I need to complete. I have a list of strings, where the first part of the string is a file name, and the second part of the string is a version number, separated by an underscore. I want to print out the string that contains that latest version for each file.

For example, with the following data set:

```
P0689.D130624.C01_0
P0689.D130624.C02_0
P0689.D130624.C04_0
P0689.D130624.C05_0
P0730.D130624.C01_0
P0730.D130624.C01_1
P0730.D130624.C01_2
P0730.D130624.C01_0
P0730.D130624.C01_1
```

my output should be:

```
P0689.D130624.C01_0
P0689.D130624.C02_0
P0689.D130624.C04_0
P0689.D130624.C05_0
P0730.D130624.C01_2
```

I figured the easiest way to do this was split the filename off as a the key to a map, then insert the version as the value if it is the current max. I would then iterate over the hash, and recombining the key/value pairs would give me my result. However, whenever I iterate over my hash, keys do not seem to be unique. The result winds up being my entire initial data set, because the versions are always in ascending order. This is probably a result of my inexperience with the perl syntax, but help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my current code:

```
my %hash = ();
foreach my $line (@F) {
    my @splt = split('_', $line);
    my $key = $splt[0];
    my $val = $splt[1];
    unless (exists $hash{$key} and $hash{$key} >= $val) {
        $hash{$key} = $val;
    }
};
while(my ($k,$v) = each %hash ) {
    print $k . '_' . $v, "\n";
};
```

Edit (2): More details on output data.

Using this script to demo:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/"
FILTER="[Pp]\(0689\|1391\|0730\)"


ls -1 $DIR*
echo -----
ls -1 $DIR* | grep "$FILTER"
echo -----
ls -1 $DIR* | grep "$FILTER" |  perl -an latest-version.pl
```

This is the EXACT output from terminal:

```
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/CONFIRM.C0668.S01125_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/CONFIRM.C0668.S26599_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0188.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0212.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C04_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C05_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0701.D130624.C98_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0702.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0706.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0706.D130624.C03_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0709.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C01_1
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C01_2
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C03_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0790.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0790.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0790.D130624.C04_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0821.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0822.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0823.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0824.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0825.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C03_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C04_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C05_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C06_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C07_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C08_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C09_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C10_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C11_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C12_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C13_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C14_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C15_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C16_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C17_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C18_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C19_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0826.D130624.C98_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C03_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C04_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C05_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C06_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C07_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C08_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C09_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C10_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C11_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C12_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C13_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C14_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C15_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C16_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C17_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C18_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C19_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0827.D130624.C98_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P1391.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P1391.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2026.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2029.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2070.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2084.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2156.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2172.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2193.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2202.D130624.C98_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2203.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C03_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C04_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C05_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C06_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C07_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C08_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C09_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C10_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C11_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C12_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C13_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C14_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C15_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C16_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C17_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C18_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C19_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C20_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C21_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C22_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C23_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2361.D130624.C98_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2362.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2363.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2363.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2364.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2365.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2429.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2518.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C03_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C04_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C05_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C06_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C07_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C08_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C09_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C10_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C11_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C12_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C13_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C14_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C15_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C16_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C17_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C18_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C19_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C20_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C21_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C22_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C23_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C24_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2656.D130624.C98_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C03_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C04_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C05_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C06_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C07_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C08_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C09_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C10_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C11_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C12_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C13_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C14_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C15_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C16_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C17_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C18_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C19_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C20_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C21_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C22_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C23_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C24_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2657.D130624.C98_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2658.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2659.D130624.C00_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P2660.D130624.C00_0
-----
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C04_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C05_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C01_1
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C01_2
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C03_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P1391.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P1391.D130624.C02_0
-----
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C04_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0689.D130624.C05_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C01_1
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C01_2
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C02_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P0730.D130624.C03_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P1391.D130624.C01_0
/app/jobsandservices/shareddata/nphdocp1/2013/06/24/P1391.D130624.C02_0
```

This is also using perl v5.10.1, as there may be environment issues afoot.

Comment: which parts should be unique in `PPPPP.DDDDDDD.CCC_X`?

Comment: For any given set of {P, D, C}, X is guaranteed to be unique for each instance of {P, D, C}. There can be an arbitrary number of unique values for each of P, D, and C.

Comment: Basically for a given {P, D, C}, I want to find the highest value of X

Comment: among `P0730.D130624.C01_0
P0730.D130624.C01_1
P0730.D130624.C01_2
P0730.D130624.C01_0
P0730.D130624.C01_1` only `P0730.D130624.C01_2` will be choosen, so your desired output is not correct

Comment: your actual output data is not coming from code above

Comment: The problem is, it is on my box. I'm using perl v5.10.1.

Comment: Have you run it in debug mode? Can you find the exact line where it's doing the wrong thing? (On the command line, `perl -d myScript.pl`)

Comment: I'm using this version and my output is same as here => **https://eval.in/51461** (ver 5.16.1)

Comment: Desired output corrected. Do you have an eval that goes back to 5.10? I'm starting to seriously think the issue is in the perl version, not the code

Comment: ok, I see your terminal output. Which lines are duplicated?

Comment: The _0 and _1 lines for P0730.D130624.C01 should be filtered out by the perl script.

Comment: I think this output could occur if the perl script is being called for each line individually, which seems like the most likely possibility at this point. If the hash is being created anew for every line, then it would never do any filtering.

Comment: Bingo. That is what was happening. It was being executed with a -n option, which was causing the hash creation and print statements at the end to be evaluated multiple times. Now I'm getting the output I was expecting.

Comment: https://eval.in/51470 So you need to be more specific with your actual environments.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The #! was one of the pieces of information that got pruned when I was cleaning up the data for the question. Turned out to be very relevant in this case. Thank you for your help though, you did a lot to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good. It returns only *the string that contains that latest version for each file* as you asked for. I think that you are just confused with the input data because the last 2 lines

```
P0730.D130624.C01_0
P0730.D130624.C01_1
```

are duplicates. Which means that for the set {P, D, C}={0730,130624,01}, X=0 and X=1 are not unique as required.
Thus your desired output shouldn't contain the last line

```
P0730.D130624.C01_1
```

In addition, please note that using `while` you can't sort the hash in order to have the desired output.

Comment: The target output should contain the latest version, which should be version _1 over version _0 (zero base numbering). The problem is, the code is actually returning the full input data set. When I iterate over the hash, there appears to be multiple instances of the same key, each with a different value.

Comment: 1) I understand that. But the latest version of {P, D, C}={0730,130624,01} is X=2 and not X=1, right?

Comment: 2) It's impossible to have multiple instances of the same key! I tried your code and I can't see the problem. Can you share your output?

Comment: You are correct. Somehow my input data is getting doubled on the feed in, which created that issue. I still haven't figured out why my hash is acting like a list, and not like a hash. I'll add the actual output data to the question.